# To reduce the Time complexity to calculate the maximum sum %n from the given array

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

I am trying to get the maximum sum%n from the specified array,my code is working fine but it is taking more than 2 seconds to give the output for larger values .
I wanted to optimize my code:

My code:

```
void get_max(long int n,long int m,long int *a)
    {

    int i,j;
    long int cu=0;
    long int max=-1000000ll;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        cu=0;
        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
            cu+=a[j];
            cu=cu%m;
            if(max<cu)
                max=cu;
        }
    }
    cout<<max<<"\n";
}
int main() {

    int t,i;
    long int m,n,e;
    long int a[100000];
    cin>>t;
   while(t--)
       {

       cin>>n;
       cin>>m;
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
           cin>>e;
           a[i]=e;
       }
       get_max(n,m,a);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not the *code* that needs optimising, it's the *algorithm*. Your algorithm is O(n^2) - you need to think of a more efficient approach to the problem.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "sum % n"? Do you mean the sum of all elements in the array modulo n?

Comment: Is this a "online judge" type thing? If so, the problem is probably that you need to use `sync_with_stdio(false);` to make `cin >> e;` faster - these programs are nearly always troubled by I/O. Unless `m` is particular known values, `%` is hard to make faster (with particular values, you can use tricks like `& m-1` if m is `2^k` or multiply with the "opposite" integer value)

Comment: Without the modulo, there is a `O(n)` solution.

Comment: sum%m means the sum we get by adding either contiguous or non contiguous elements and n is given by user I have to get the maximum value for sum%m. m-given by user n-is the sizeof array